# Jump animation still play's when I land

Tags: python, pygame

So I been trying make it so my jump animation will stop playing when it land's on the ground and will start playing my idle animation, but that is not working. My jump animation still keeps playing even though I already landed, it only stops when I move left or right. https://gyazo.com/ea6ae3f84d8d999fb9b36d7fbecafb72

I have tried this code out

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        playerman.direction = "jump"

    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left" and playerman.direction == "idlel":
            playerman.direction = "idlel"
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")


move = pygame.image.load("WASD.png")


# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.idle =[pygame.image.load("player_idel_1.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_2.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_3.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_4.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_5.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_6.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_7.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_8.png")
                            ]

        self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left1.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left2.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left3.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left4.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left5.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left6.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left7.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left8.png")
                         ]
        self.right = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right3.png")]
        
        self.left = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left3.png")]

        self.jump = [pygame.image.load("Player_jump1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump3.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump4.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump5.png")]

        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idle]
        self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idlel]
        self.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.right]
        self.left = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2, image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.left]
        self.jump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.jump]
        self.fps = 10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.dierection = "idleleft"
        self.dierection = "jump"
        self.next_frame_time = 0
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
        pygame.draw.rect(self.color,self.rect)
    
    def draw(self):
        if self.direction == "idle":
            image_list = self.idle
        if self.direction == "right":
            image_list = self.right
        if self.direction == "left":
            image_list = self.left
        if self.direction == "idlel":
            image_list = self.idlel
        if self.direction == "jump":
            image_list = self.jump

         

        # Is it time to show the next animation frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_frame_time ):
            # set the time for the next animation-frame
            inter_frame_delay = 1000 // self.fps   
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_frame_delay  # in the future
            # move the current image to the next (with wrap-around)
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len( image_list ):
                self.anim_index = 0
                    
        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.get_rect() )
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 3
        player_rect.centery -= 13
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)
        


class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())


class Rule:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(350,445,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(300,-9.1,40,500,green)
platform2 = Platform(330,451,2000,40,green)
platform3 = Platform(2300,-9.1,40,500,green)

# Drawing Rule
rule1 = Rule(340,-9.1,220,500,green)
rule2 = Rule(20000,-9,1,5,green)

# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3]

rules = [rule1,rule2]


# draws map
platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
Level = [
"                                         1   1",
"                                         1    ",
"                         1  1        111 1    ",
"                         1  1       111  1    ",
"                         11 1      1111 11    ",
"                         1  1     11111  1    ",
"                         1  1    1111111 1    ",
"           1   1   111   1 11   1111111  1    ",
"           1   1  11111     1  11111111          ",]

for iy,row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_platforms = Platform(ix*50,iy*50.2,50,50,(255,255,255))
            platforms.append(new_platforms)
    
            

# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()
    for Rule in rules:
        Rule.draw()

x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    


    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += playerman.speed

    if playerman.y > 410:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y -= playerman.fall

    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            x_change = -7
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
           
        # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y


    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed

        playerman.direction = "right"
        
       
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed
        playerman.direction = "left"
        


    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left":
            playerman.direction = "idlel"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "right":
                playerman.direction = "idle"
                

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        playerman.direction = "jump"

    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left" and playerman.direction == "idlel":
            playerman.direction = "idlel"
            

    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px

    move_right = keys[pygame.K_d]
    move_left = keys[pygame.K_a]
    if move_right: 
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed     # <---
    if move_left:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed     # <---

    platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect() for p in platforms] # get_rect()
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    cI = player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list)
    if cI >= 0:
        # undo movement of platforms dependent on the direction and intersection distance
        dx = 0
        if move_right: 
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].left - player_rect.right
        if move_left:
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].right - player_rect.left
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= dx
            Platform.get_rect() # update rectangle
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= dx             # <---

##############                
  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right

                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                py -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0
            

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(rule1.rect):
        window.blit(move,(-40,-100))
    
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Is `self.dierection` supposed to be `self.direction` ?  There's a couple of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a `Player.stopJump()` function.

```
def stopJump( self, from_where=None ):
    if ( from_where != None ):
         print( "DEBUG: stopJump() called from [%s]" % ( from_where ) )
    self.isJump     = False
    self.direction  = "idle"
    self.anim_index = 0
    # ... plus whatever else
```

Then whenever in the code jumping is stopped, for example when the player collides with the platform, instead of clearing `isJump`:

```
playerman.isJump = False
```

do

```
playerman.stopJump( "Part1" )
```

Which also resets the animation-list back to idle.

Comment: It only play's that one idle and it play's it really fast https://gyazo.com/161e03b680a04bfbe3327cfc8c501f0d

Comment: @Windowman - Do you have any calls to `stopJump()` that are unnecessary?  It sounds like it's being called all the time (or suchlike).  Like under `# About isJump`?

Comment: @Windowman  - modify `stopJump()` to take a string paramter, and then add a line to print it out, then modify every call like:  `stopJump( "HERE1" )` and `stopJump( "HERE2" )`.  Find the one that's being continuously printed, and work out why that's so.

Comment: @Windowman - it's hard to debug now, because I have to *imagine* the changes you've made, and what the state of the new source is.

Comment: @Windowman - that code still has the call to `stopJump()`, the first call to it in the main loop.  This is changing the animation to idle, every frame, whenever `playerman.isJump` is False.

Comment: So I tryed the stopJump("HERE1") and  I get this error playerman.stopJump("idle")
TypeError: stopJump() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @Windowman - yeah, you have to modify `stopJump()` to take the new argument, and then print it in the function body.

Comment: I tried to modify it to take direction but its not working.

Comment: @Windowman - please see edit.  Obviously you don't want "Part1" to be the argument for all of them, just make it different - part1, part2, .. etc.